# Changing orientation of all polygons at once with numeric value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, rotate

I want to change the orientation of the raster/polygons with a numeric value around the centroid of the total grid.

I have tried `rotate($geometry, 45)` in the Field Calculator but nothing happened.

[image: QGIS canvas]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run your expression in the processing tool "Geometry by Expression". This will actually change the geometry and add it to a new layer.

Running this in the Field Calculator does have no effect. It does only add the values to a new field.

If it is for visual purposes only, you can also use this expression in your symbology tab of the layer and add a Geometry Generator renderer.

Comment: problem is as mentioned by @Erik that every individual polygon is rotated but I want all of them at once

Comment: @N_LLC that is a different question. You can solve that using [Rotate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisrotatefeatures) with the full grid center as anchor point

Comment: @BERA I have updated the question, thank you for clearing this up

Answer (score 6):

Update the `"geometry"` field in the field calculator, then the desired result should "happen". Please be aware that this will change your original geometry, so maybe export first and then edit.

This will also rotate every single geometry around itself, so if you want to rotate all features at once, you might have to fixate the rotation around the centroid of the bounding box of the whole layer. Please check the [official documentation on rotate()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=rotate#rotate) for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'polygon'* with five features in it, see the image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to change the orientation of each feature with a numeric value (45 degrees)*.

```sql
SELECT "id", rotate(geometry, 45) AS geom
FROM "polygon"
```

The output point layer with its attribute table will look like

[image: result]

It rotates geometry clockwise about the center of the original geometry’s bounding box.